# Certain pages opened by selenium driver are blank with no content

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The webdriver accesses the web page, but there is no content. Entering inside the page HTML there is just this script.:

There is no body at all. I tried to enter any other website inside the same browser and it works. But for this website opened by the selenium driver it does not do anything. Opening the website from my profile browser is completely fine. I asuseme it is some configuration that i am missing.

f1xx.v1xx=v1xx;f1xx[374148]=window;f1xx[647467]=e8NN(f1xx[374148]);f1xx[125983]=n3EE(f1xx[374148]);f1xx[210876]=(function(){var P6=2;for(;P6 !== 1;){switch(P6){case 2:return {w3:(function(v3){var v6=2;for(;v6 !== 10;){switch(v6){case 2:var O3=function(W3){var u6=2;for(;u6 !== 13;){switch(u6){case 2:var o3=[];u6=1;break;case 14:return E3;break;case 8:U3=o3.H8NN(function(){var Z6=2;for(;Z6 !== 1;){switch(Z6){case 2:return 0.5 - B8NN.P8NN();break;}}}).D8NN('');E3=f1xx[U3];u6=6;break;case 3:j3++;u6=5;break;case 6:u6=!E3?8:14;break;case 5:u6=j3 < W3.length?4:9;break;case 1:var j3=0;u6=5;break;case 9:var U3,E3;u6=8;break;case 4:o3.A8NN(q8NN.F8NN(W3[j3] + 92));u6=3;break;}}};var u3='',k3=T8NN(O3([28,26,28,-43])());v6=5;break;case 5:var p3=0,S3=0;v6=4;break;case 4:v6=p3 < k3.length?3:6;break;case 3:v6=S3 === v3.length?9:8;break;case 7:(p3++,S3++);v6=4;break;case 6:u3=u3.X8NN('{');v6=14;break;case 9:S3=0;v6=8;break;case 14:var R3=0;var t3=function(b3){var n6=2;for(;n6 !== 16;){switch(n6){case 4:n6=R3 === 1 && b3 === 2?3:9;break;case 7:n6=R3 === 3 && b3 === 51?6:14;break;case 13:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-2,2).i8NN(0,1));n6=5;break;case 5:return (R3++,u3[b3]);break;case 18:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-6,6).i8NN(0,5));n6=5;break;case 9:n6=R3 === 2 && b3 === 171?8:7;break;case 2:n6=R3 === 0 && b3 === 32?1:4;break;case 10:n6=R3 === 6 && b3 === 74?20:19;break;case 6:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-6,6).i8NN(0,5));n6=5;break;case 1:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-10,10).i8NN(0,8));n6=5;break;case 19:n6=R3 === 7 && b3 === 72?18:17;break;case 3:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-4,4).i8NN(0,3));n6=5;break;case 8:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-7,7).i8NN(0,6));n6=5;break;case 17:t3=x3;n6=5;break;case 20:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-7,7).i8NN(0,6));n6=5;break;case 14:n6=R3 === 4 && b3 === 134?13:12;break;case 12:n6=R3 === 5 && b3 === 76?11:10;break;case 11:u3.G8NN.N8NN(u3,u3.i8NN(-10,10).i8NN(0,8));n6=5;break;}}};var x3=function(Z3){var H8=2;for(;H8 !== 1;){switch(H8){case 2:return u3[Z3];break;}}};return t3;break;case 8:u3+=q8NN.F8NN(k3.M8NN(p3) ^ v3.M8NN(S3));v6=7;break;}}})('JU7*1&')};break;}}})();f1xx.w8=function(){return typeof f1xx[210876].w3 === 'function'?f1xx[210876].w3.apply(f1xx[210876],arguments):f1xx[210876].w3;};f1xx.l8=function(){return typeof f1xx[210876].w3 === 'function'?f1xx[210876].w3.apply(f1xx[210876],arguments):f1xx[210876].w3;};function n3EE(U8S){function k2S(h8S,z8S,x8S,i8S,W8S){var J8S=2;for(;J8S !== 9;){switch(J8S){case 4:v8S[8]="Property";try{var P8S=2;for(;P8S !== 8;){switch(P8S){case 3:try{var Y8S=2;for(;Y8S !== 3;){switch(Y8S){case 2:v8S[5]=v8S[2];v8S[5]+=v8S[1];v8S[5]+=v8S[8];Y8S=4;break;case 4:v8S[0][0].Objectv8S[5];Y8S=3;break;}}}catch(x2S){}v8S[7][v8S[0][4]]=v8S[9].value;P8S=8;break;case 2:v8S[9]={};v8S[3]=(1,v8S[0][1])(v8S[0][0]);v8S[7]=[v8S[3],v8S[3].prototype][v8S[0][3]];v8S[9].value=v8S[7][v8S[0][2]];P8S=3;break;}}}catch(i2S){}J8S=9;break;case 2:var v8S=[arguments];v8S[2]="def";v8S[1]="ine";J8S=4;break;}}}function r2S(A8S){var c8S=2;for(;c8S !== 5;){switch(c8S){case 2:var N8S=[arguments];return N8S[0][0].Function;break;}}}function o2S(E8S){var Z8S=2;for(;Z8S !== 5;){switch(Z8S){case 2:var u8S=[arguments];return u8S[0][0];break;}}}var F8S=2;for(;F8S !== 59;){switch(F8S){case 11:k8S[9]="stra";k8S[6]="**ab";k8S[2]="Q3";k8S[48]="E";F8S=18;break;case 6:k8S[5]="ct";k8S[4]="";k8S[4]="r";k8S[3]="";F8S=11;break;case 65:a2S(j2S,"test",k8S[46],k8S[17]);F8S=64;break;case 3:k8S[7]="";k8S[7]="optimiz";k8S[8]="";k8S[8]="d";F8S=6;break;case 53:k8S[13]+=k8S[48];k8S[13]+=k8S[48];k8S[89]=k8S[90];k8S[89]+=k8S[7];F8S=49;break;case 60:a2S(r2S,"apply",k8S[46],k8S[49]);F8S=59;break;case 18:k8S[72]="esidual";k8S[90]="**";k8S[3]="3E";k8S[86]="e";k8S[44]="t";F8S=26;break;case 61:a2S(o2S,k8S[16],k8S[23],k8S[59]);F8S=60;break;case 26:k8S[23]=0;k8S[46]=1;k8S[45]="EE";k8S[52]="3";k8S[62]="U";F8S=21;break;case 49:k8S[89]+=k8S[86];k8S[17]=k8S[1];k8S[17]+=k8S[52];k8S[17]+=k8S[45];F8S=45;break;case 64:a2S(o2S,k8S[89],k8S[23],k8S[13]);F8S=63;break;case 42:k8S[54]+=k8S[48];k8S[94]=k8S[8];k8S[94]+=k8S[3];k8S[94]+=k8S[48];F8S=38;break;case 2:var k8S=[arguments];k8S[1]="";k8S[1]="";k8S[1]="l";F8S=3;break;case 32:k8S[59]+=k8S[3];k8S[59]+=k8S[48];k8S[16]=k8S[90];k8S[16]+=k8S[4];k8S[16]+=k8S[72];k8S[54]=k8S[86];k8S[54]+=k8S[3];F8S=42;break;case 38:k8S[31]=k8S[6];k8S[31]+=k8S[9];k8S[31]+=k8S[5];k8S[13]=k8S[2];F8S=53;break;case 63:a2S(o2S,k8S[31],k8S[23],k8S[94]);F8S=62;break;case 21:k8S[49]=k8S[44];k8S[49]+=k8S[52];k8S[49]+=k8S[45];k8S[59]=k8S[62];F8S=32;break;case 45:var a2S=function(w8S,L8S,l8S,V8S){var t8S=2;for(;t8S !== 5;){switch(t8S){case 2:var G8S=[arguments];k2S(k8S[0][0],G8S[0][0],G8S[0][1],G8S[0][2],G8S[0][3]);t8S=5;break;}}};F8S=65;break;case 62:a2S(G2S,"push",k8S[46],k8S[54]);F8S=61;break;}}function G2S(C8S){var M8S=2;for(;M8S !== 5;){switch(M8S){case 2:var m8S=[arguments];return m8S[0][0].Array;break;}}}function j2S(H8S){var p8S=2;for(;p8S !== 5;){switch(p8S){case 2:var X8S=[arguments];return X8S[0][0].RegExp;break;}}}}function e8NN(d6){function C0(s6){var U6=2;for(;U6 !== 5;){switch(U6){case 2:var S6=[arguments];return S6[0][0].String;break;}}}function r0(E6){var O6=2;for(;O6 !== 5;){switch(O6){case 2:var m6=[arguments];return m6[0][0];break;}}}function x0(h6,o6,g6,J6,j6){var y6=2;for(;y6 !== 8;){switch(y6){case 3:t6[4]="define";try{var D6=2;for(;D6 !== 8;){switch(D6){case 4:t6[9].value=t6[6][t6[0][2]];try{var A6=2;for(;A6 !== 3;){switch(A6){case 1:t6[3]+=t6[1];t6[3]+=t6[2];t6[0][0].Objectt6[3];A6=3;break;case 2:t6[3]=t6[4];A6=1;break;}}}catch(Q0){}t6[6][t6[0][4]]=t6[9].value;D6=8;break;case 2:t6[9]={};t6[5]=(1,t6[0][1])(t6[0][0]);t6[6]=[t6[5],t6[5].prototype][t6[0][3]];D6=4;break;}}}catch(a0){}y6=8;break;case 2:var t6=[arguments];t6[2]="perty";t6[1]="";t6[1]="Pro";y6=3;break;}}}function i0(G6){var z6=2;for(;z6 !== 5;){switch(z6){case 2:var c6=[arguments];return c6[0][0].Math;break;}}}function w0(T6){var M6=2;for(;M6 !== 5;){switch(M6){case 2:var q6=[arguments];return q6[0][0].String;break;}}}var V6=2;for(;V6 !== 84;){switch(V6){case 21:I6[58]="i8";I6[51]=1;I6[99]=1;I6[99]=0;I6[92]=I6[58];I6[92]+=I6[69];I6[92]+=I6[69];V6=29;break;case 3:I6[9]="";I6[9]="F";I6[3]="";I6[3]="H";I6[4]="NN";V6=14;break;case 64:I6[75]+=I6[69];I6[75]+=I6[69];I6[19]=I6[3];I6[19]+=I6[13];V6=60;break;case 10:I6[2]="";I6[5]="B8";I6[18]="P";I6[36]="M8";V6=17;break;case 14:I6[7]="";I6[7]="8";I6[6]="";I6[6]="T";V6=10;break;case 89:Z7(w0,"charCodeAt",I6[51],I6[55]);V6=88;break;case 86:Z7(R0,"apply",I6[51],I6[14]);V6=85;break;case 87:Z7(n7,"unshift",I6[51],I6[29]);V6=86;break;case 76:I6[45]=I6[8];I6[45]+=I6[7];I6[45]+=I6[4];V6=73;break;case 60:I6[19]+=I6[69];I6[33]=I6[9];I6[33]+=I6[7];I6[33]+=I6[4];I6[72]=I6[1];I6[72]+=I6[7];I6[72]+=I6[4];V6=76;break;case 2:var I6=[arguments];I6[1]="";I6[1]="q";I6[8]="A";V6=3;break;case 85:Z7(n7,"splice",I6[51],I6[92]);V6=84;break;case 66:Z7(n7,"join",I6[51],I6[93]);V6=90;break;case 69:Z7(n7,"sort",I6[51],I6[19]);V6=68;break;case 88:Z7(w0,"split",I6[51],I6[32]);V6=87;break;case 48:I6[93]+=I6[4];I6[48]=I6[18];I6[48]+=I6[13];I6[48]+=I6[69];I6[75]=I6[5];V6=64;break;case 72:Z7(n7,"push",I6[51],I6[45]);V6=71;break;case 29:I6[14]=I6[69];I6[14]+=I6[13];I6[14]+=I6[69];I6[29]=I6[67];I6[29]+=I6[13];I6[29]+=I6[69];I6[32]=I6[2];V6=39;break;case 67:Z7(i0,"random",I6[99],I6[48]);V6=66;break;case 71:Z7(r0,"String",I6[99],I6[72]);V6=70;break;case 68:Z7(r0,"Math",I6[99],I6[75]);V6=67;break;case 17:I6[38]="D";I6[2]="";I6[2]="X8";I6[67]="";I6[67]="";V6=25;break;case 52:I6[24]+=I6[13];I6[24]+=I6[69];I6[93]=I6[38];I6[93]+=I6[7];V6=48;break;case 90:Z7(r0,"decodeURI",I6[99],I6[24]);V6=89;break;case 25:I6[67]="G";I6[69]="";I6[13]="8N";I6[69]="N";V6=21;break;case 70:Z7(C0,"fromCharCode",I6[99],I6[33]);V6=69;break;case 39:I6[32]+=I6[69];I6[32]+=I6[69];I6[55]=I6[36];I6[55]+=I6[69];I6[55]+=I6[69];I6[24]=I6[6];V6=52;break;case 73:var Z7=function(K6,Q6,a6,B6){var N6=2;for(;N6 !== 5;){switch(N6){case 2:var L6=[arguments];x0(I6[0][0],L6[0][0],L6[0][1],L6[0][2],L6[0][3]);N6=5;break;}}};V6=72;break;}}function R0(f6){var Y6=2;for(;Y6 !== 5;){switch(Y6){case 2:var W6=[arguments];return W6[0][0].Function;break;}}}function n7(p6){var e6=2;for(;e6 !== 5;){switch(e6){case 2:var X6=[arguments];return X6[0][0].Array;break;}}}}f1xx.q8S=function(){return typeof f1xx[533032].T7E === 'function'?f1xx[533032].T7E.apply(f1xx[533032],arguments):f1xx[533032].T7E;};f1xx.A7=function(){return typeof f1xx[244094].S2 === 'function'?f1xx[244094].S2.apply(f1xx[244094],arguments):f1xx[244094].S2;};f1xx[460531]=285;f1xx.a7=function(){return typeof f1xx[244094].R2 === 'function'?f1xx[244094].R2.apply(f1xx[244094],arguments):f1xx[244094].R2;};f1xx.o2=function(){return typeof f1xx[237115].n2 === 'function'?f1xx[237115].n2.apply(f1xx[237115],arguments):f1xx[237115].n2;};f1xx.B7=function(){return typeof f1xx[244094].R2 === 'function'?f1xx[244094].R2.apply(f1xx[244094],arguments):f1xx[244094].R2;};f1xx[533032]=(function(){var T8S=2;for(;T8S !== 9;){switch(T8S){case 2:var B8S=[arguments];B8S[7]=undefined;B8S[8]={};B8S[8].T7E=function(){var y8S=2;for(;y8S !== 145;){switch(y8S){case 2:var g8S=[arguments];y8S=1;break;case 148:y8S=55?148:147;break;case 45:g8S[80].P43=['r43'];g8S[80].J43=function(){var F1E=function(){var J1E;switch(J1E){case 0:break;}};var W1E=!(/\u0030/).l3EE(F1E + []);return W1E;};g8S[47]=g8S[80];y8S=63;break;case 37:g8S[83].J43=function(){var d1E=function(){return new RegExp('/ /');};var e1E=(typeof d1E,!(/\x6e\x65\x77/).l3EE(d1E + []));return e1E;};g8S[31]=g8S[83];g8S[93]={};g8S[93].P43=['j43'];y8S=52;break;case 147:B8S[7]=61;return 38;break;case 28:g8S[89].J43=function(){var R1E=function(){return parseInt("0xff");};var T1E=!(/\x78/).l3EE(R1E + []);return T1E;};g8S[21]=g8S[89];g8S[15]={};y8S=42;break;case 63:g8S[38]={};g8S[38].P43=['p43'];g8S[38].J43=function(){var v1E=false;var O1E=[];try{for(var r1E in console){O1E.e3EE(r1E);}v1E=O1E.length === 0;}catch(L1E){}var n1E=v1E;return n1E;};y8S=60;break;case 89:g8S[24].J43=function(){var M2E=function(p2E,Y2E){if(p2E){return p2E;}return Y2E;};var u2E=(/\x3f/).l3EE(M2E + []);return u2E;};y8S=88;break;case 71:g8S[53]=g8S[50];g8S[13]={};g8S[13].P43=['W43'];g8S[13].J43=function(){var s2E=function(){var D2E=function(z2E){for(var g2E=0;g2E < 20;g2E++){z2E+=g2E;}return z2E;};D2E(2);};var h2E=(/\x31\u0039\u0032/).l3EE(s2E + []);return h2E;};y8S=67;break;case 80:g8S[42]=g8S[37];g8S[70]={};g8S[70].P43=['W43'];g8S[70].J43=function(){var q2E=function(){return ('aa').endsWith('a');};var S2E=(/\u0074\u0072\x75\u0065/).l3EE(q2E + []);return S2E;};g8S[76]=g8S[70];g8S[10]={};g8S[10].P43=['p43'];y8S=100;break;case 127:y8S=g8S[68] < g8S[6].length?126:149;break;case 1:y8S=B8S[7]?5:4;break;case 110:g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[97]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[2]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[77]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[42]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[63]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[90]);g8S[88]=[];y8S=134;break;case 42:g8S[15].P43=['W43'];g8S[15].J43=function(){var l1E=function(){return ('aa').charCodeAt(1);};var Q1E=(/\x39\u0037/).l3EE(l1E + []);return Q1E;};g8S[97]=g8S[15];g8S[83]={};g8S[83].P43=['j43'];y8S=37;break;case 52:g8S[93].J43=function(){var U1E=function(m1E,K1E){return m1E + K1E;};var t1E=function(){return U1E(2,2);};var k1E=!(/\u002c/).l3EE(t1E + []);return k1E;};g8S[16]=g8S[93];g8S[48]={};y8S=49;break;case 126:g8S[78]=g8S[6][g8S[68]];try{g8S[12]=g8S[78]g8S[33]?g8S[64]:g8S[36];}catch(c2E){g8S[12]=g8S[36];}y8S=124;break;case 150:g8S[68]++;y8S=127;break;case 5:return 49;break;case 115:g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[76]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[61]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[71]);y8S=112;break;case 149:y8S=(function(O8S){var D8S=2;for(;D8S !== 22;){switch(D8S){case 1:D8S=f8S[0][0].length === 0?5:4;break;case 4:f8S[6]={};f8S[2]=[];f8S[4]=0;D8S=8;break;case 10:D8S=f8S[9][g8S[14]] === g8S[64]?20:19;break;case 13:f8S[6][f8S[9][g8S[30]]]=(function(){var K8S=2;for(;K8S !== 9;){switch(K8S){case 3:return R8S[5];break;case 2:var R8S=[arguments];R8S[5]={};R8S[5].h=0;R8S[5].t=0;K8S=3;break;}}}).t3EE(this,arguments);D8S=12;break;case 5:return;break;case 8:f8S[4]=0;D8S=7;break;case 15:f8S[1]=f8S[2][f8S[4]];f8S[7]=f8S[6][f8S[1]].h / f8S[6][f8S[1]].t;D8S=26;break;case 12:f8S[2].e3EE(f8S[9][g8S[30]]);D8S=11;break;case 7:D8S=f8S[4] < f8S[0][0].length?6:18;break;case 18:f8S[8]=false;D8S=17;break;case 24:f8S[4]++;D8S=16;break;case 20:f8S[6][f8S[9][g8S[30]]].h+=true;D8S=19;break;case 16:D8S=f8S[4] < f8S[2].length?15:23;break;case 25:f8S[8]=true;D8S=24;break;case 17:f8S[4]=0;D8S=16;break;case 6:f8S[9]=f8S[0][0][f8S[4]];D8S=14;break;case 14:D8S=typeof f8S[6][f8S[9][g8S[30]]] === 'undefined'?13:11;break;case 2:var f8S=[arguments];D8S=1;break;case 11:f8S[6][f8S[9][g8S[30]]].t+=true;D8S=10;break;case 23:return f8S[8];break;case 19:f8S[4]++;D8S=7;break;case 26:D8S=f8S[7] >= 0.5?25:24;break;}}})(g8S[88])?148:147;break;case 152:g8S[88].e3EE(g8S[55]);y8S=151;break;case 4:g8S[6]=[];g8S[1]={};g8S[1].P43=['W43'];y8S=8;break;case 85:g8S[57].J43=function(){function I2E(Z2E,o2E){return Z2E + o2E;};var b2E=(/\u006f\x6e[ \f\u1680\u3000\v\u00a0\n\ufeff\u205f\u2029\u2000-\u200a\t\u202f\u2028\r\u180e]{0,}\x28/).l3EE(I2E + []);return b2E;};y8S=84;break;case 123:y8S=g8S[94] < g8S[78][g8S[46]].length?122:150;break;case 112:g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[58]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[66]);y8S=110;break;case 21:g8S[59].J43=function(){var i1E=typeof Q3EE === 'function';return i1E;};g8S[49]=g8S[59];g8S[85]={};g8S[85].P43=['p43'];y8S=32;break;case 100:g8S[10].J43=function(){var x2E=typeof U3EE === 'function';return x2E;};g8S[61]=g8S[10];g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[21]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[31]);y8S=96;break;case 76:g8S[35].J43=function(){var C2E=function(){debugger;};var f2E=!(/\x64\u0065\x62\u0075\u0067\u0067\x65\x72/).l3EE(C2E + []);return f2E;};g8S[11]=g8S[35];g8S[50]={};g8S[50].P43=['j43','r43'];g8S[50].J43=function(){var X2E=function(){return 1024 * 1024;};var j2E=(/[5-8]/).l3EE(X2E + []);return j2E;};y8S=71;break;case 25:g8S[51].J43=function(){var H1E=function(){return (![] + [])[+ ! +[]];};var P1E=(/\x61/).l3EE(H1E + []);return P1E;};g8S[58]=g8S[51];g8S[59]={};g8S[59].P43=['p43'];y8S=21;break;case 60:g8S[63]=g8S[38];g8S[27]={};g8S[27].P43=['W43'];g8S[27].J43=function(){var N1E=function(){return ('x').toLocaleUpperCase();};var w2E=(/\x58/).l3EE(N1E + []);return w2E;};g8S[66]=g8S[27];y8S=55;break;case 84:g8S[62]=g8S[57];y8S=83;break;case 8:g8S[1].J43=function(){var o1E=function(){return ('xy').substring(0,1);};var A1E=!(/\u0079/).l3EE(o1E + []);return A1E;};g8S[7]=g8S[1];g8S[3]={};g8S[3].P43=['W43'];y8S=13;break;case 32:g8S[85].J43=function(){var B1E=typeof d3EE === 'function';return B1E;};g8S[90]=g8S[85];g8S[89]={};g8S[89].P43=['j43'];y8S=28;break;case 119:g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[5]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[16]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[9]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[49]);y8S=115;break;case 96:g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[47]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[53]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[65]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[7]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[62]);g8S[6].e3EE(g8S[11]);y8S=119;break;case 55:g8S[35]={};g8S[35].P43=['r43'];y8S=76;break;case 13:g8S[3].J43=function(){var G1E=function(){return ('c').indexOf('c');};var q1E=!(/['"]/).l3EE(G1E + []);return q1E;};g8S[5]=g8S[3];g8S[4]={};g8S[4].P43=['r43'];g8S[4].J43=function(){var S1E=function(){'use stirct';return 1;};var x1E=!(/\x73\x74\x69\x72\u0063\u0074/).l3EE(S1E + []);return x1E;};g8S[2]=g8S[4];g8S[8]={};y8S=17;break;case 122:g8S[55]={};g8S[55][g8S[30]]=g8S[78][g8S[46]][g8S[94]];g8S[55][g8S[14]]=g8S[12];y8S=152;break;case 88:g8S[77]=g8S[24];g8S[57]={};g8S[57].P43=['p43'];y8S=85;break;case 67:g8S[65]=g8S[13];g8S[24]={};g8S[24].P43=['j43'];y8S=89;break;case 134:g8S[64]='H43';g8S[36]='Q43';g8S[46]='P43';g8S[14]='F43';y8S=130;break;case 17:g8S[8].P43=['j43','r43'];g8S[8].J43=function(){var c1E=function(E1E){return E1E && E1E['b'];};var V1E=(/\x2e/).l3EE(c1E + []);return V1E;};g8S[9]=g8S[8];g8S[51]={};g8S[51].P43=['j43','W43'];y8S=25;break;case 151:g8S[94]++;y8S=123;break;case 128:g8S[68]=0;y8S=127;break;case 49:g8S[48].P43=['j43','r43'];g8S[48].J43=function(){var y1E=function(){return 1024 * 1024;};var a1E=(/[5-78-8]/).l3EE(y1E + []);return a1E;};g8S[71]=g8S[48];g8S[80]={};y8S=45;break;case 83:g8S[37]={};g8S[37].P43=['r43'];g8S[37].J43=function(){var A2E=function(){if(false){console.log(1);}};var G2E=!(/\x31/).l3EE(A2E + []);return G2E;};y8S=80;break;case 130:g8S[33]='J43';g8S[30]='c43';y8S=128;break;case 124:g8S[94]=0;y8S=123;break;}}};T8S=3;break;case 3:return B8S[8];break;}}})();f1xx[374148].b2JJ=f1xx;f1xx[244094]=(function(K2){return {S2:function(){var v2,M2=arguments;switch(K2){case 2:v2=(M2[0] - M2[2]) * M2[1] * M2[3] + M2[4];break;case 35:v2=(M2[4] - M2[2]) / M2[3] + M2[1] + M2[0];break;case 20:v2=-M2[2] / M2[4] - M2[1] + M2[3] + M2[0];break;case 32:v2=-M2[3] * M2[0] - M2[2] + M2[1];break;case 16:v2=(M2[1] + M2[2]) * M2[4] * M2[3] - M2[0];break;case 22:v2=(M2[1] + M2[3]) * M2[2] - M2[0];break;case 8:v2=M2[3] >>> M2[1] * M2[2] & M2[0];break;case 4:v2=M2[1] - M2[4] + M2[3] + M2[2] - M2[0];break;case 30:v2=(-M2[3] - M2[0]) / M2[1] + M2[2];break;case 3:v2=M2[2] - M2[1] - M2[0];break;case 28:v2=M2[1] >>> M2[0];break;case 12:v2=M2[0] & M2[2] | M2[1];break;case 10:v2=M2[0] - M2[1] + M2[2] - M2[3];break;case 9:v2=M2[2] * M2[1] * M2[3] / M2[4] - M2[0];break;case 5:v2=M2[0] + M2[2] - M2[1];break;case 6:v2=M2[2] << M2[0] | M2[4] >>> M2[1] - M2[3];break;case 14:v2=M2[3] + M2[2] - M2[1] - M2[0];break;case 23:v2=(M2[1] - M2[2] + M2[4]) * M2[3] - M2[0];break;case 26:v2=(M2[4] + M2[1] - M2[3]) / M2[0] + M2[2];break;case 24:v2=M2[3] * M2[2] * M2[4] * M2[1] - M2[0];break;case 0:v2=M2[0] - M2[1];break;case 29:v2=M2[2] << M2[1] & M2[0];break;case 27:v2=(M2[4] + M2[1] - M2[3]) * M2[0] + M2[2];break;case 34:v2=M2[1] * M2[3] * M2[2] - M2[0];break;case 1:v2=(M2[2] / M2[0] + M2[1]) * M2[4] - M2[3];break;case 11:v2=M2[1] >> M2[2] | M2[0];break;case 7:v2=M2[2] >>> M2[4] * M2[3] + M2[0] & M2[1];break;case 21:v2=M2[0] / M2[2] + M2[1];break;case 19:v2=-M2[1] / M2[2] * M2[3] + M2[0];break;case 15:v2=M2[2] / M2[1] - M2[0];break;case 31:v2=(M2[2] - M2[0]) * M2[3] - M2[1];break;case 33:v2=M2[1] + M2[0] & M2[2];break;case 18:v2=M2[0] / M2[2] + M2[3] - M2[1];break;case 25:v2=M2[0] + M2[1];break;case 13:v2=M2[2] >> M2[1] & M2[3] | M2[0];break;case 17:v2=M2[2] - M2[1] + M2[0];break;}return v2;},R2:function(s2){K2=s2;}};})();function f1xx(){}f1xx.U2=function(){return typeof f1xx[237115].n2 === 'function'?f1xx[237115].n2.apply(f1xx[237115],arguments):f1xx[237115].n2;};f1xx[237115]=(function(){var F2=[arguments];F2[2]=2;for(;F2[2] !== 1;){switch(F2[2]){case 2:return {n2:(function(){var Q2=[arguments];Q2[7]=2;for(;Q2[7] !== 18;){switch(Q2[7]){case 1:Q2[4]=4;Q2[7]=5;break;case 8:Q2[7]=98 >= f1xx.w8(51)?7:6;break;case 5:Q2[7]=f1xx.l8(2) !== 93?4:3;break;case 14:Q2[6]=16;Q2[7]=13;break;case 13:Q2[7]=f1xx.l8(76) === 80?12:11;break;case 9:Q2[3]=99;Q2[7]=8;break;case 19:Q2[8]=0;Q2[7]=18;break;case 12:Q2[5]=48;Q2[7]=11;break;case 6:Q2[7]=f1xx.l8(134) !== 75?14:13;break;case 4:Q2[1]=88;Q2[7]=3;break;case 2:Q2[7]=10 > f1xx.w8(32)?1:5;break;case 10:Q2[2]=67;Q2[7]=20;break;case 11:Q2[7]=29 > f1xx.l8(74)?10:20;break;case 7:Q2[9]=27;Q2[7]=6;break;case 20:Q2[7]=f1xx.w8(72) != 55?19:18;break;case 3:Q2[7]=28 === f1xx.w8(171)?9:8;break;}}})()};break;}}})();f1xx.W2=function(){return typeof f1xx[244094].S2 === 'function'?f1xx[244094].S2.apply(f1xx[244094],arguments):f1xx[244094].S2;};f1xx[230480]=489;f1xx.n8S=function(){return typeof f1xx[533032].T7E === 'function'?f1xx[533032].T7E.apply(f1xx[533032],arguments):f1xx[533032].T7E;};f1xx.n8S();function v1xx(){return "-0Ci%5EH%3E0O%5EJa%0F%01LIPJ&%05_K_R%258LYAG=;LNTE&0V%5EXI$&LLTR)=LIYG8%14CQ%15E.6hKBB%203%5BKBS%3E:GLYP)%0F%7BGR@&%0ALXTUpuLEAC$.UEU_1%0AhNCO%3C0EuTP+9BKEC1!XyET#;PQ%11%5D=%3CYN%5EQd;V%5CXA+!XX%1FQ/7SXXP/'LZPT/;Cd%5EB/.@OSA&.DICO:!L%5E%5Ej%25%22RXrG90L%07JU:9%5E%5EJU/;SC_Ajk%17%1D%01%10z4T%04%1F%5D80DZ%5EH90cSAC11V%5EP%5D:=VDEI'.%5BE%5EV)4%5BI%11N+&*IPU%22.DOEt/$BOBR%020VNTT1'BD_O$2%17Q%0A%02b=VYY%0Fq%0AOIPJ)%7DVXVS'0Y%5EB%08)4%5BFT%0Fq.%7Dy~h1%0DzfyR%3E%25eO@S/&CQUI)%20ZO_R1%0AdO%5DC$%3CBGno%0E%10hxTE%25'SOC%5D=%3CCBrT/1RDEO+9DQ_G%3C%3CPKEI8%7B%5BK_A?4POB%5D)4%5BFJ,1&CKRM1%16XDEC$!%1A~HV/.%5EDUC2%1AQQ%5ET#0Y%5EPR#:YQ%5EJ.uUX%5EQ90EY%11V%259%5BSWO&9L_CJ1'UP_U1%0Ah%5DTD.'%5E%5CTT%15&TXXV%3E%0AQ__E%3E%3CXDJC26RZEO%25;%17L%5ETj!RYE%1Cj.hYTJ/;%5E*%5C%5Dk%3CDoUA/%7D%1E%0A%17%00j%3CDiYT%258R%02%18%06ls%17FPH-&%19C_B/-xL%19J+;P%03%11%1AjeL%0CJN/4SOCU1zLgb~%07%19%05%04ik%06%1Dc~a%08y%7B%07QST%25%22DOC%06:'XZTT%3E%3CRY%11K+%25GC_A1;BGSC8.@C_B%25%22%19N%5EE?8RDE%08n6SInG91%5DL%5DG9%20CEA@%22#Tp%7DK)3%5BuJs%04%18vyzc%0E%0Aeo%7Fb%0F%07rxnq%0F%17pfJV+'DOJC8'XXJQ#;SEF%7D=%3CYN%5EQ%0E0CORR#:YaT_%1C4%5B_T%7B1b%07%1C%01G)d%0EL%04%16xe%0FISD%7C7%03%1F%02%14r0Q%13%05%17~eV%1C%00%14/0%0E%18%02%1E%7D0%07%1B%04%13sa%05%19%05%16%7DbU%1EU%17/c%03L%00%5D:9BMXH9.XH%5BC)!L@%5EO$.%5BK_A?4POB%5D#1LICC+!Ro%5DC'0Y%5EJg%08%16sowa%02%1C%7Da%7Dk%04%1Ag%7Bcu%1E%00a%7Di%7F%104UIUC,2_C%5BM&8YEAW8&C_GQ2,M%1A%00%14ya%02%1C%06%1Es.POEc&0ZO_R9%17N~PA%044ZOJO$%3CC%0AAT%256RYB%5D80VNHu%3E4COJN/%3CPBE%5D#;DOCR%080QECC1%0AhNCO%3C0EuDH='VZAC..SOSS-.LDPP#2V%5E%5ETd9VDVS+2RY%11%1Bwu%15%08JE+9%5ByTJ/;%5E_%5C%5Dw.TBCI'0LGTR%22:SQny90%5BO_O?8hOGG&%20V%5ET%5D%7B.V@P%5E1%3C_F%0B%061%3CZMJT/%25%5BKRC1&TX%5EJ&%01XZJT/&GE_U/.uXXG$ugKDJ1%3CDg%5ED#9RQVC%3E%01%5EGT%5C%25;ReW@90CQBC/1Lq%5ED%200T%5E%11g8'VSl%5D%15%0A@OSB8%3CAOCy96ECAR%153BDR%5De%05_K_R%258%7Dy%1E%08%3E0D%5E%19Q#;SEF%08$4ACVG%3E:E%04DU/'vMTH%3E%7CLCBe%22'XGT%5D-0Co%5DC'0Y%5Es_%031LI%5DO/;CbTO-=CQ_G%3C%3CPKEI8%7B%5BK_A?4POB%08#;SOIi,%7D%5BK_Acu%0B%0A%01%06ls%17DPP#2V%5E%5ETd9VDVS+2RY%1FO$1RR~@b9VDV%14cu%0B%0A%01%5D9!V%5EDU1%05xye%5D80F_TU%3E.%18%12U%12%7DxQLR%15geQ%1C%02%0B~7%04I%1CE%7F6%0E%07%04%10sl%1A%1CU%13(x%04K%00@e1%18QSC80DBXR1%0AhZYG$!XGPU1%05_K_R%258%7Dy%1Cs%0B.COIR1'UPXB1:YF%5EG..@C_B%25%22l%0DUI)%20ZO_Rm%08lN%5EE?8RDEb/!RIEO%25;%7COHp+9BOl%5D9!EC_A1%00ygpu%01%10sugc%04%11xxnq%0F%17pfJn/4SFTU9%16_X%5EK/.GBPH%3E:Z@B%5D?&RXpA/;CQPV:9NQAT%25!X%5EHV/.huBC&0YCDK%15%20Y%5DCG:%25RNJy%153ONCO%3C0EuTP+9BKEC1%16XDEC$!%1A%5EHV/.Q__E%3E%3CXDJy:=VDEI'.huW%5E.'%5E%5CTT%15%20Y%5DCG:%25RNJG:%25%5BCRG%3E%3CXD%1EL9:YQ%5BU%25;GQWT%258tBPT%09:SOJy%15;%5EMYR'4EOJA/!v%5EET#7B%5ET%5D?;SOWO$0SQPJ=4NYJA/!cC%5CC1%02rhvj%151RHDA%15'RDUC80EuXH,:LhD@,0EQRJ#0Y%5EfO.!*Q%1EG(d%0EN%00G%7Bm%0FI%05%12zl%0F%13%01E.m%05%18WE.dT%1D%06CxzU%1E%06E%7CbRHR%13%7D6%03O%06%12(cS%18%06%12)7%0FHS%1F.1SL%1ED%7D3%03%1F%06%1F(c%0F%1F%02%12/c%04K%05%1E%7C1%04%1F%05%15)bT%18%04%16/%7B%5DZV%5D/-TOAR#:Y%0ABR+6%5CQ%7CC94%17eW@%196EOTH1%0Ah%5DTD.'%5E%5CTT%15&TXXV%3E%0AQDJV?&*QGC$1XX%11%1Bwu%15hCO+;%17zPS&w%17%0C%17%0680YNTT/'%17%17%0C%06h%18RYP%06%053QyRT/0Y%08JA/!rREC$&%5EE*%5D+%25GO_B%09=%5EFU%5D%15%0A@OSB8%3CAOCy?;@XPV:0SQ%1E%1E.a%00%07W@)f%1A%1AW%10yx%03H%02Eg6%02I%08%0B%7Fc%0E%13%1C%10.%60U%07%02G%7B3%18N%1ECe.POEv+'VGTR/'LFTH-!*QTK#!LIYG8%16XNTg%3E.XDTT8:EQCC9%25XDBC%1E0O%5EJO9%10SMT%5D.:ZkDR%258V%5EXI$.D%5E%5ET+2RQTT8:E%0AFO%3E=%17C%5CA1&R%5EpR%3E'%5EHDR/.DICI&9%7BOWR19VDVS+2RQI%0B00UXP%0B11XGpS%3E:ZKEO%25;tE_R8:%5BFTT1%22RHUT##RXJy%190%5BO_O?8hcuc%15%07RI%5ET.0EQRG&9UKRM1&EIJQ#;%1AN%5EEj%25EEAU1%22%5EDBI)%3EDQCC&:VNJCd&CKRMd%3CYNT%5E%053%1F%0DAN+;CE%5CL9r%1E%0A%0F%06gdL@BI$%25LNXU+7%5BOU%5D%15%0A@OSB8%3CAOCy/#VFDG%3E0LDPP#2V%5E%5ET1&RDUO$2LYET#;PCW_1%22%5EDUI=%7BTBCI'0LN%5EE?8RDEc&0ZO_R1%22%5ENEN1%22%5ENEN1!XyET#;PQCG$1XGJR8%3CZQRG$#VYJR/&CQ%5EH80VNHU%3E4CORN+;POJ%1914GZ%5DO)4CC%5EHe-%1A%5DFQg3XX%5C%0B?'%5BO_E%251RNJ%7D%257%5DORRj%1AU@TE%3E%08LKSI8!LF%5EE+!%5EE*%5D%3E'%5EGJE/%3C%5BQ%11%1Bwu%16%1AJN+&x%5D_v8:GOCR3.DO_B1%0EXH%5BC)!%17eSL/6CwJ@&:XXJn/4SFTU9%16_X%5EK/o%17%5ECS/.XDCC+1NYEG%3E0TBPH-0LLPM/%3CZKVC1&RDU%5D#&tBCI'0%1F%03%11%00lu%16CBk%257%5EFT%0Ecu%11%0C%11Q#;SEF%08)=EE%5CCjh%0A%17%11S$1RLXH/1LXTK%25#RQE*:0LF%5EA1&BIRC9&L%06%11%5D=0UM%5D%5D/%7BD%5EPE!%7B%5EDUC2%1AQ%02%16V%224Y%5E%5EK%20&%10%03%11%18jx%06";}(function(){var s3S=f1xx;var Y7=[arguments];Y7[6]={};s3S.n8S();Y7[2]=function(g7){var z7=[arguments];s3S.n8S();z7[2]=s3S.w8(185);z7[6]=JSON[s3S.w8(15)]((function(){var w7=[arguments];w7[6]={};w7[6][s3S.w8(99)]=z7[0][0];w7[6][s3S.w8(115)]=Y7[6];s3S.n8S();return w7[6];})s3S.w8(157));if(window[s3S.w8(47)]){z7[5]=fetch(z7[2],(function(){var V7=[arguments];V7[2]={};s3S.n8S();V7[2][s3S.l8(121)]=s3S.l8(142);V7[2][s3S.w8(91)]={};V7[2][s3S.w8(91)][s3S.l8(80)]=s3S.l8(165);V7[2][s3S.w8(52)]=z7[6];return V7[2];})s3S.l8(157));}else {z7[9]=new (window[s3S.w8(72)] || ActiveXObject)(s3S.w8(93));z7[9]s3S.l8(51);z7[9]s3S.w8(68);z7[9]s3S.w8(35);}};try{Y7[3]=/\u0057\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\u0077\u0073[^\n\r\u2028\u2029][^\n\r\u2028\u2029]{0,}\x72\x76\x3a\u0031\x31/;Y7[5]=Y7[3]s3S.w8(21);Y7[4]=function(L7){var O7=[arguments];O7[6]=new Date()s3S.l8(172)s3S.w8(54);s3S.q8S();try{Y7[6][O7[6]]=O7[0][0];}catch(r1){(1,Y7[2])(r1);}};(1,Y7[4])(s3S.l8(110));Y7[9]=function(){var y7=[arguments];y7[2]={};y7[9]=! !window[s3S.w8(72)] && ! !window[s3S.w8(71)];y7[5]=(function(){var E7=[arguments];E7[9]={};E7[9][s3S.l8(38)]=s3S.l8(43);E7[9][s3S.l8(84)]=null;E7[9][s3S.l8(65)]={};E7[9][s3S.l8(5)]=null;E7[9][s3S.l8(91)]={};E7[9][s3S.l8(91)][s3S.w8(161)]=s3S.l8(24);E7[9][s3S.l8(64)]=s3S.l8(148);E7[9][s3S.w8(75)]=!1;s3S.n8S();return E7[9];})s3S.w8(157);y7[7]=function(){var k7=[arguments];for((k7[2]={},k7[3]=0);k7[3] < arguments[s3S.l8(187)];k7[3]++){k7[8]=void 0;k7[7]=arguments[k7[3]];for(k7[8] in k7[7]){Object[s3S.l8(158)][s3S.w8(30)]s3S.w8(77) && (s3S.w8(31) === Object[s3S.w8(158)][s3S.w8(54)]s3S.w8(77)?k7[2][k7[8]]=(1,y7[7])(!0,k7[2][k7[8]],k7[7][k7[8]]):k7[2][k7[8]]=k7[7][k7[8]]);}}return k7[2];};y7[8]=function(G7){var d7=[arguments];if(s3S.l8(152) === typeof d7[0][0]){return d7[0][0];}if((/\x61\x70\u0070\x6c\u0069\u0063\u0061\x74\u0069\u006f\u006e\u002f\u006a\x73\x6f\u006e/i)s3S.w8(21) || s3S.l8(134) === Object[s3S.l8(158)][s3S.l8(54)]s3S.l8(77)){return JSONs3S.l8(15);}d7[8]=[];for(d7[9] in d7[0][0]){d7[0][0]s3S.l8(30) && d7[8][s3S.w8(180)](encodeURIComponent(d7[9]) + s3S.l8(119) + encodeURIComponent(d7[0][0][d7[9]]));}return d7[8]s3S.w8(104);};y7[1]=function(){var t7=[arguments];t7[9]={};t7[9][s3S.l8(40)]=function(){};s3S.q8S();t7[9][s3S.w8(99)]=function(){};t7[9][s3S.w8(171)]=function(){};t7[6]=t7[9];t7[5]=new XMLHttpRequest();t7[3]=(function(){var D7=[arguments];D7[6]={};D7[6][s3S.l8(40)]=function(p7){var X7=[arguments];s3S.n8S();t7[6][s3S.w8(40)]=X7[0][0];return t7[3];};D7[6][s3S.l8(99)]=function(A43){s3S.q8S();var m7=[arguments];t7[6][s3S.l8(99)]=m7[0][0];return t7[3];};D7[6][s3S.w8(171)]=function(B43){s3S.q8S();var h7=[arguments];t7[6][s3S.w8(171)]=h7[0][0];return t7[3];};D7[6][s3S.w8(25)]=function(){t7[5]s3S.w8(25);};D7[6][s3S.w8(143)]=t7[5];s3S.q8S();return D7[6];})[s3S.w8(157)]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I had to integrate :

disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled

The websites that have this are bot protected and recognize the selenium as a bot. This trick did the thing, and now they can be opened. Except that another solution was to insert the IP in the host files for the direct websites links.